# i want to change the gravity of list view that inside Relative layout trough the adapter

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.golan.wazap.UsersListActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
android:background="@drawable/chat_background">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myUsers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

this is my XML i dont know if i need to add something

```
public class UsersListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final LinkedList<String> chat;
private final Context context;


public UsersListAdapter(Context context, LinkedList<String> chat) {
    this.context = context;
    this.chat = chat;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return chat.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int i) {
    return chat.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View recycledView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (recycledView == null) recycledView = new TextView(context);
    TextView tv = ((TextView) recycledView);
    tv.setText(getItem(i));
    tv.setTextSize(30);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bubble);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);




    return recycledView;
}
```

}
this is my adapter
ad you can see i tried to change the gravity to CENTER_HORIZONTAL but it didn`t work. i need it to be in the center of the line in that list view

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the android:gravite of LinearLayout to center_horizontal or the android:layout_gravite of ListView to center_horizontal.I don't see the RelativeLayout.